# forgot user name and password for phpMyAdmin using Lamp Fedora

Tags: phpmyadmin, lamp, mysql

can't log into it anyway and I even edited the config.inc.php file.
another question is my local host's ip address is 10.0.2.15, but I have to access the phpMyAdmin using the 127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin. And early before I also edited the phpMyAdmin.conf file on this part

```
# Apache 2.4

<RequireAny>

  Require ip 127.0.0.1

  Require ip ::1

</RequireAny>
```

```
# Apache 2.2
```

#Order Deny,Allow

#Deny from All

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1

Allow from ::1
```

I changed the 
   Order Deny,Allow

Deny from All

```
Allow from no
```

to
   #Order Deny,Allow

#Deny from All

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

can anybody help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

reinstall `phpmyadmin` if necessary !!

Comment: that doesn't work either... how to install phpadmin? and also the address 10.0.2.15 and 127.0.0.1 can both go to the apache page...

Comment: Are you running windows / linux or mac?

Comment: I am running fedora on virtual box

Comment: is your apache server running?

Comment: I have tried this, service mysqld restart, httpd restart, both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Reset your MySQL root password using the following steps, and then login to phpMyAdmin as root with your new password.

1. Stop all the running instances of MySQL.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```
2. Run MySQL in safe mode.

   ```
   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
   ```
3. Login to MySQL as root user without password.

   ```
   mysql -u root mysql
   ```
4. Set your MySQL root password.

   ```
   update user set Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') where User = 'root';  
   flush privileges;   
   exit;
   ```

   In the first command replace the string `newpassword` with your own new MySQL root password.
5. Stop mysqld.

   ```
   sudo killall mysqld
   ```
6. Restart MySQL.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
   ```
7. Login to phpMyAdmin as root with your new password.